# Parameter Estimation in a Gaussian Environment

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

In Simon Haykin's [Neural networks and learning machines](https://cours.etsmtl.ca/sys843/REFS/Books/ebook_Haykin09.pdf) Page 106.

This paper defines a function and intends to derive it to obtain the target result w.
$$
\mathscr E(\mathbf w) = \frac{\sum_i^N(d_i - \mathbf w^T \mathbf x_i)^2}{2} + \lambda \frac{\Vert \mathbf w \Vert^2}{2}
$$
Finally, w can be written in the following form：
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat {\mathbf w}_{\mathrm {MAP}} (N) & = [R_{xx} (N) + \lambda \mathbf I]^{-1}\ r_{dx} (N) \\\\
\hat R_{xx} (N) & = - \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_j^T 
,\quad \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_j\ is\ a\ outer\ product\\\\
\hat r_{dx} (N) & = - \sum_{j=1}^N \mathbf x_i d_i
\end{aligned} \tag{1}
$$

But in my personal derivation:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathscr E (\mathbf w) & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N (d_i^2 - 2 d_i \mathbf w^T \mathbf x_i + \mathbf w^T \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_i^T \mathbf w) + \frac{\lambda}{2} \mathbf w^T \mathbf w \\\\
\Rightarrow \mathscr E^{'} (\mathbf w) & = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N (-2 d_i \mathbf x_i + 2 \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_i^T \mathbf w) + \lambda \mathbf w \\\\
& = - \sum_{i=1}^N d_i \mathbf x_i + \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_i^T \mathbf w + \lambda \mathbf w \\\\
& = - \sum_{i=1}^N d_i \mathbf x_i + (\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_i^T + \lambda I) \mathbf w 
\end{aligned}
$$

Then let $\mathscr E^{'} (\mathbf w)$ be 0:
$$
\hat {\mathbf w}_{\mathrm {MAP}} (N) = [\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf x_i \mathbf x_i^T + \lambda I]^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^N d_i \mathbf x_i \tag{2}
$$

Are (1) and (2) equal? Or did my derivation go wrong?

---

Update:

This formula is similar to [Wiener-Hopf equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter)

---

Update 2:

In "Matrix formulation of the Wiener–Hopf Equations", section 2.4 from "Adaptive Filter Theory"

Wiener solution can be expressed as

$$
\mathbf w_0 = \mathbf R^{-1} \mathbf p,\quad \mathbf R = \mathbb E[\mathbf u  \mathbf u^T]
$$

It more like the form I wrote.

Comment: Why not do it in a matrix form?

Comment: @Royi I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: it seems you git what I mean in your _Update 2_.

Comment: @Royi What I want to know is whether (1) and (2) can be converted to each other?  They don't look equal.